# Fetch _all_remote_specs: undefined method 'list' - Rails on Mac OSx Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a new rails application on my Mac running Lion. I installed Rails using RubyGems. I also went ahead and installed the XCode command line tools. When I attempt to create a new rails application I get an error that reads:

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/source.rb:253:in `fetch_all_remote_specs': undefined method`list' for # (NoMethodError)

I have tried reinstalling Rails using RubyGems but no luck. Can anyone give me a clue as to what is missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should probably upgrade bundle. That's what I did.

`gem update bundle`